# What does this code mean? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone explain me second line? 
Why without this it won't work correct?

```
dataStuff.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.Tag] = grouped[a.Tag] || [];
    grouped[a.Tag].push(a);
});
```

Comment: Try to explain what `grouped[a.Tag].push(a);` does first. Your answer relies on your understanding of this very line.

Comment: What won't work correctly? What is the input and expected output? The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataStuff.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.Tag] = grouped[a.Tag] || []; //if  grouped[a.Tag] array is undefined make it an array
    grouped[a.Tag].push(a);                //try to push into array.
});
```

Explaining your code.

The line

`grouped[a.Tag].push(a);` is supposed to `push` a values into the array `grouped[a.Tag]`. If at all this `grouped[a.Tag]` array is undefined you will get a error saying `grouped[a.Tag] is undefined`. So to overcome this problem this line

`grouped[a.Tag] = grouped[a.Tag] || [];` is used.

Here `grouped[a.Tag] || []` if at all `grouped[a.Tag]` is undefined your above line will be equivalent to

`grouped[a.Tag] = [];`  That is create a new array.

Else if `grouped[a.Tag]` is defined then you don't have to do anything so just assign it to itself.

So the idea is if `grouped[a.Tag]` is undefined then create a new array else do nothing as you are good to go.